Cannot connect to crash database due to slow connection
Today I had a crash on an application and the Report problem was uploading problem information, but due to my slow connection the upload was interrupted with this message: Cannot connect to crash database, please check your Internet connection. HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway.
This problem is recurrent. Sometimes I have a crash and try to open the bug.


Any 500 series error is in the Internet not in the local OS so there is noting anyone here can suggest to fix it.
